# Simplifying $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X}_n)(Y_i - \bar{Y}_n)$

Tags: statistics, summation

I would like to show
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X}_n)(Y_i - \bar{Y}_n) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}U_iV_i+\bar{U}_n\bar{V}_n$$
where $\bar{X}_n = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and similarly for $\bar{Y}_n$, $\bar{U}_n$, and $\bar{V}_n$; $U_i = X_i - \mu_x$, $V_i = Y_i - \mu_y$, where $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are constants.

My attempt:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X}_n)(Y_i - \bar{Y}_n) &= \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(X_i-\mu_x)-(\bar{X}_n-\mu_x)][(Y_i-\mu_y)-(\bar{Y}_n-\mu_y)] \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu_x)(Y_i-\mu_y)-\dfrac{2}{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu_x)(\bar{Y}_n-\mu_y)\\
&+(\bar{X}_n-\mu_x)(\bar{Y}_n-\mu_y)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
This doesn't quite match what I'm looking for. Is my desired equation wrong, or is my work wrong?

Comment: I think you have a sign error in what you are trying to prove and that it should be $\frac{1}{n}\sum (X_i - \overline{X})(Y_i-\overline{Y}) =  \frac{1}{n}\sum U_iV_i - \overline{U}\overline{V}$. It's hard to see what is inside the sum and what is outside the sum in your last line, but it looks like you have forgotten to multiply by $n$ in the middle term (from summing over $i=1,\ldots,n$ or forgot that $\sum X_i = n\overline{X}$). That would reduce it to the form I quoted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X_n)(Y_i-\overline Y_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overline Y_n - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \overline X_n + \sum_{i=1}^n \overline X_n \, \overline Y_n \tag 1
$$

Since $\overline X_n$ does not change as $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \overline X_n = X_n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i,
$$
and that is $\displaystyle X_n \cdot n \overline Y_n,$ and in the same way we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overline Y_n = Y_n \cdot n \overline X_n.
$$
The last sum in $(1)$ is just
$$
\overline X_n \overline Y_n + \cdots + \overline X_n \overline Y_n.
$$
Can you do the rest?